# iPhone Target launches on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

So I'm trying to make a separate iPad and iPhone version for this app I'm working on and I've already made two different targets. My iPad target works as expected as it won't launch on an iPhone. However, my iPhone target still launches on both iPhone and iPad. I've also set the main interface in the deployment info as iPhone.

Here's a picture of the settings:
[image]

Does anyone know why my iPhone target isn't exclusively targeting iPhones?

EDIT: To clarify, I am building two separate versions (one for iPad, one for iPhone). My iPhone target is able to launch on both iPad and iPhone, which is not what I want. I want my iPhone target to only open on an iPhone.

Comment: It's actually stated in the App Store guidelines: "iPhone Apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution".  (2.10)  https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#functionality

Comment: You cannot prevent users from installing your iPhone app on an iPad.  At this point you should be designing for both.

Comment: Ah!!! I didn't know that, thanks for the link

Comment: @DShaw originally I was designing it as a universal but who I'm designing the app for wants separate versions for different pricing, etc

Comment: You can make an iPad only version. For the iPhone version, just make an iPad layout that says "Get the iPad version" or something to that effect.

Comment: @DShaw thanks for the tip, I'm going to think about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an Apple policy decision that iPads can run all iPhone applications at iPhone resolution; it is a licensing term that you cannot take steps to override that policy decision (e.g. by detecting your environment and declining to offer any functionality).

So there's nothing you can do. Apple has spoken.

Comment: I don't want a Universal app sorry should've clarified (now I'm reading it again and it's a little unclear). I only want to have an iPhone app but it is able to launch on iPad somehow.

Comment: Apple doesn't allow you to block installation or launch of an iPhone app on iPads. So chalk it down to the centralised policy conflicting with your preference if necessary.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that! Thanks I was really confused there, if you edit the answer I'll mark you